# Terminal commands- (ps -ef | grep tomcat)

Tags: shell, terminal

Hey guys was trying to just host my files on the development and as well as jump server and had to use the command ps -ef | grep tomcat. Does anyone know what the command actually does? And how does it actually work?

Comment: @martinhilary- Are you going to use these commands in a tomcat application? or asking the usage of `ps-ef | grep tomcat` terminal command.

Comment: @RameshSubramanian hey I have been using this command in a tomcat application I just wanna know what does the ps -ef do and how does the pipe(' | ') actually pass data and search for anything that has tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

The command `ps -ef | grep tomcat` list out the processes which contains the word tomcat in the argument of the process. To execute these kind of commands in java language, you have to use `Runtime.exec()` or `ProcessBuilder` . Sample code is attached below.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Process p = null;
    String command = "ps -ef | grep tomcat";
    try {
        // p = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
           p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
           BufferedReader br[] = new BufferedReader[2];
           br[1] = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
           br[0] = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

           String line = null;
           while ((line = br[0].readLine()) != null){
               System.out.println(line);
           }


           try {
               br[0].close();
           } catch (Exception a) {}
           try {
               br[1].close();
           } catch (Exception a) {}
    } 
    catch (Exception grrr) {
    }
    finally {
       try {
           closeStreams(p);
           p.destroy();
       } catch (Exception r) {}
   }
}

static void closeStreams(Process p) throws IOException {
    p.getInputStream().close();
    p.getOutputStream().close();
    p.getErrorStream().close();
}
```

}

Comment: Just to clarify so what are the commands ps -ef for specifically because I understand that the grep will search the keyword added specifically. Thx for your quick response!